# Understand git --graph colors "logic"

Tags: git, logging, graph, colors

if i try to display my git history with

git log  --graph --decorate

[image: output of: git log --graph --decorate]
I've problem to understand the logic of the color changes on the branch:

on commit *56c477* there is a change in color from green to red in **master** branch while on *d8fe756* on the **fix2** branch there is no change in color (still green). So what is the logic behind color changes in git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's to make the output more human readable

For your particular case, I think it's because your commits `0abd2` has 2 childs, so the green is kept. Then, because `56c477` is right before the merge commit (`f21f4`), the color changes so you can see it.

I suppose it would be different if you had inverted the merge for the commit `0ffb0`

You can use `git rebase` to avoid complex graph, and merge everytime to the same branch (for example, when you finished your work on the branch `fix3`, you can do something like this (some steps can be avoided )

```
# sync your repo
git checkout master
git fetch
git merge --ff origin/master
# rebase your working branch to master
git checkout -
git rebase master
# merge with --no-ff (so you will see the branch in your graph)
git checkout -
git merge --no-ff gix3
```